# Phone encryption on OnePlus 2 cyanogenmod 13

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-two

I've just installed Cyanogenmod on my OnePlus Two. When I go to Settings>Security> Encrypt Phone and perform a encryption, the system just reboot and back to the lock screen without any encryption steps.

Does anyone know how can I enable encryption? I need this to switch on my work profile.

Answer (score 0):

I at one point used the July 16 nightly build of CyanogenMod with encryption. I would recommend using the stock OxygenOS recovery before doing this.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot 2]